# How do I know what function is holomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, holomorphic-functions

It's given function $f(z)=(x+jy)^2$. I need to calculate integral $\int_{\Gamma } f \left ( z \right )dz$ along the curve $\Gamma$ which the circular line around $z_0 = 0$ and radius $r = 1$ represents.

In solution says that is 0, because function is holomorphic and curve is closed.

Comment: Everything you need can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem. The function is just $z^2$, and it can be easily shown by means of the Cauchy Riemann equations that any polynomial is a holomorphic function.

Comment: Is your question on why $f(z)$ is holomorphic?

Comment: Holomorphic means differentiable with respect to its complex variable $z = x + iy$.  This is a stronger requirement than having partial derivatives w.r.t. x and y.  A check that is sometimes convenient is change the variables $x,y$ in $f(x,y)$ to the variables $z = x + iy$ and $\overline{z} = x - iy$.  Then the Cauchy-Riemann conditions acquire this simple form:
$$
{\partial f \over \partial \overline{z}} = 0.
$$

Your function can be written $f(z) = z^2$, which does not explicitly involve $\overline{z}$, hence meets the Cauchy-Riemann condition in the latter form.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know what function is holomorphic?

Holomorphic functions satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. You can verify

$$f(z) = (x^2 - y^2) + i(2xy)$$

Let $u(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$ and $v(x, y) = 2xy$. Note that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$